# TTY pre-login in QWERTY instead of AZERTY

Tags: tty, keyboard-layout, localectl

I am french and usually types with `AZERTY` layout.

My `TTYs` virtual consoles (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>fN</kbd>) are in `QWERTY` before and after login. It's painful, because I have to log each time in `QWERTY`.

Once logged in I can run `loadkeys en` (in reality I type **lo**q**dkeys en**) and it works, I am then in `AZERTY` until the next reboot. This is very annoying !

In other hand on my graphical session under X (XFCE4 as DE) I am in `AZERTY`.

My distro is a Debian Buster.

What I tested :

```
user@host:~$ localectl list-keymaps
Failed to read list of keymaps: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

but apparently [this is a false positive](https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2020/07/02/reconfiguring-the-time-zone-locales-and-keymaps-in-sabayon-linux/)

```
user@host:~$ localectl 
System Locale: LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
   VC Keymap: fr
  X11 Layout: fr
   X11 Model: pc105
 X11 Variant: oss_latin9
```

all seems OK.

```
 root@host:~# grep -r loadkeys /etc
```

no launches in `/etc`

A fresh install of Debian Buster runs correctly in pre-login I type in `AZERTY`.

I'm running out of ideas ...

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

In case this could be usefull to someone.

I stupidly missed an important package for the TTY : [console-setup](https://packages.debian.org/console-setup)